# How to block service calls in angularjs resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

In my angularJS application I have a route in that route I am resolving  some http service calls .

```
 .when("/Dashboard", {
        controller: 'dashboardController',
        templateUrl: 'app/Dashboard/template/dashboard.html,
        resolve: {
           authorize: ['AuthService', function (authService) {
                return authService.validateSession();
            }],
           dashboardData: ['DashboardService', function (dashboardService) {
                 var deffered = $q.defer();
                dashboardService.getDashboardData(function (response) {
                    deffered.resolve(response);
                });
                return deffered.promise;
            }], 
        }
  }
```

Here is my AuthService:

```
    app.factory('AuthService', factory);
    factory.$inject = ['$http',  '$q', '$cookies', '$location', '$rootScope'];

    function authService($http, $routeParams, $q, $cookies, $location, $rootScope) {
     /***** removed the code for clarity *****/

     function validateUserSession(cb) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if ($cookies.get("userId")) {
               checkUserSession.create(function (response) {
                    if (response.data == "Valid") {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }
                    else {
                        var Url = "/Login";
                        var userId= $cookies.get('userId', { path: '/' });
                        if (userId) {
                            Url = Url + "/" + userId;
                        }
                        $location.path(Url);                        
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                var Url = "/Login";
                var userId= $cookies.get('userId', { path: '/' });
                if (userId) {
                    Url = Url + "/" + userId;
                }
                $location.path(Url);
                $q.reject();
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        };
   }
```

I want to block the second call dashboardData on resolve if the first call authorize will invalid due to either $cookies.get("userId") returns undefined or  checkUserSession service returns invalid .How this will be done in angularjs?

Comment: resolve variables are injectable, try injecting `authorize` into `dashboardData` with `function (dashboardService, authorize)` (_I'm not sure if that will work_)

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey I also has 4 more functions in my resolve and also have more than 30 routes defined with resolve